# My TexStudio has stopped working, constantly says citation ' x ' is undefined on page y

Tags: bibtex, citing, harvard-style

I am unsure why, but for some reason my Texstudio program is no longer working informing me that all my references in the `.bib` file are not working. It has a number of warnings including citation missing and File ended while scanning use of `\harvardurl`.

I find it strange that it was previously working until I began a new section, but now one of them work.

Edit: This is the bib file entries giving error

```
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{ref.bib}
@online{HyperPhysicsEM,
    author = "Rod Nave",
    title = "{Electromagnetic Waves}",
    year = "2005", 
    url  = "http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/emwavecon.html",
    OPTurldate  = {accessed: 25/02/2018}        
}
@online{Microwave,
    author = "Jim Lucas",
    title = "{What Are Microwaves?}",
    year = "2018", 
    url  = "https://www.livescience.com/50259-microwaves.html",
    OPTurldate  = {25/02/2018}      
}

@online{Transducer,
    author = "CyberPhysics",
    title = "{The Piezoelectric Transducer}",
    year = "2018", 
    url  = "http://www.cyberphysics.co.uk/topics/medical/Ultrasound/PETransducer.html",
    note = "(accessed: 23/02/2018)"     
}


@online{Peffect,
    author = "D. Vatansever and E Siores and T. Shah",
    title = "{Alternative Resources for Renewable Energy: Piezoelectric and Photovoltaic Smart Structures}",
    year = "2012", 
    url  = "https://www.intechopen.com/books/global-warming-impacts-and-future-perspective/alternative-resources-for-renewable-energy-piezoelectric-and-photovoltaic-smart-structures",
    OPTurldate  = { 23/02/2018}     
}

@online{InversePeffect,
    author = "Carmen Emily Yang ",
    title = "{What is the Piezoelectric Effect?}",
    year = "2016", 
    url  = "http://www.electronicdesign.com/power/what-piezoelectric-effect",
    OPTurldate  = { 23/02/2018}         
}

@online{PulseEcho ,
    author = "Barnana Pal",
    title = {Pulse-echo method can't measure wave attenuation accurately },
    year = "2014",
    url  = "http://www.electronicdesign.com/power/what-piezoelectric-effect",
    OPTurldate  = { 23/03/2018}     
}

@online{HarbourPorpoise,
    author = "Lee A. Miller and Magnus Wahlberg",
    title = {Echolocation by the harbour porpoise: life in coastal waters},
    year = "2013",
    url  = "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3625834/",
    OPTurldate  = { 26/03/2018}     
}

@online{UltrasonicFrogs,
    author = "Albert S. Feng and Peter M. Narins and Chun-He Xu and Wen-Yu Lin and Zu-Lin Yu and Qiang Qiu and Zhi-Min Xu and Jun-Xian Shen",
    title = {Ultrasonic communication in frogs},
    year = "2006",
    url  = "https://www.nature.com/articles/nature04416.epdf?referrer_access_token=LNiCFtk3I0dn2v_AQJi7L9RgN0jAjWel9jnR3ZoTv0Mg8z7v5gDUqEkMtxgbkmfnvtnkk6K-DSpQAwlhEv7S09o7Z1CcRAGZ-jRhIZrCBxEnNLEm-Hh2WWuS7KsV2QRDgRk1XxPWezWv0JDp4VGznNDREMvAIetTrYWhs-_WUHSXAiAcnqL4ZFrjt7BaN85qwq1dToDeNugpAcT9jN9--j-DNo5sboys5-h8E0-gCYE%3D&tracking_referrer=www.nature.com",
    OPTurldate  = { 30/03/2018}     
}
\end{filecontents*}

\bibliography{ref}
```

With document class `report`, reference style `asgm` and `natbib` is the citation management package. Lastly I do use `url` package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please post actual code, rather than a screenshot of code. Please also post the contents of the bib entry that's giving you problems. And, do tell us which document class you employ and which citation management packages, if any, you load in the preamble. And, do let us know if you load the `url` package. Finally, do note that TeXstudio is just a front-end to LaTeX and BibTeX; stating that "my Texstudio program is no longer working" is not exactly helpful.

Comment: Is that error in line 117 the first error you get? Once Latex finds errors, it's not rare that it loses track completely. The 'undefined' citations can very well be the results of that.

Comment: Please make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)

Comment: although this really can't be answered without a minimum working example with bibliography, the error stating that `\begin{thebibliography}` is ended by `\end{document}` indicates that the error is *in* the bibliography, something that isn't "closed" so that `\end{thebibliography}` isn't being properly detected.  this is most likely an absent closing brace, or perhaps a vagrant `%` that is causing such a brace to be ignored.  to be more precise, we do need to see code.

Comment: Apologies, first time posting Mico, and yes Remco that is the first error I get.

Comment: The URL string of the `UltrasonicFrogs` entry contains one or more syntax errors and hence can't be processed correctly.

Comment: @Mico thats the direct url, but i tried without that reference at all and it still has the same error message, excluding `UltrasonicFrogs`

Comment: @LukeFarrell - I don't know what you mean by "the direct url". For sure, it's no good: As long as I omit the offending URL  (while keeping the rest of the `UltrasonicFrogs` entry), I can get the rest of the code to compile just fine.

Comment: @Mico I by direct url, i meant it was the url for that webpage, so i cannot get rid of it if i want to use it. But when i tried omitting the url myself it is still not working

Comment: @LukeFarrell - A comment "it is still not working" is not all that helpful. *What* isn't "working"? I posted an answer, to show that suppressing one URL at least succeeds in getting the rest of the bib entries typeset. In the anwer, I also raise the issue that the problem is associated with `agsm`, which is near-obsolete by now. For sure, `agsm` is not very good at handling general URL strings.

Answer (score 1):

Several comments:

- The `agsm` bibliography style does not recognize a field called `OPTurldate`. If you want the acccessed-on date to show up in the formatted bibliography, you'll need to change the field name to `note`.
- Do be aware that the `agsm` bib style does not feature an entry type called `@online`; the catch-all `@misc` entry type will be used instead.
- The `author` fields are encased in both curly braces and double quotes, preventing the application of sentence style (the `agsm` default). I'd remove that.
- Because the `url` field of the entry `UltrasonicFrogs` contains a `%` character as well as several `_` (underscore) characters, it cannot be processed correctly using the `agsm` setup (which falls back on `\harvardurl`, which isn't nearly as robust as `\url` is to the presence of such "special" characters). After some testing, I found that the only way to typeset the rest of the entry successfully (as well as all other bib entries) was to rename the `url` field to a string not recognized by `agsm`.

Finally, a fairly broad question: *Why* do you employ the `agsm` style? It's been around more or less unchanged since 1991 [!], it has a lot of quirks, the way it typesets URLs is rather quaint (to put it politely), and it doesn't handle general URL strings correctly. In my view, `agsm` is far more trouble than it can be worth.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}   
\begin{filecontents*}{ref.bib}
@online{HyperPhysicsEM,
    author = "Rod Nave",
    title = "Electromagnetic Waves",
    year = "2005", 
    url = "http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/emwavecon.html",
    note = {Accessed on 25/02/2018}        
}
@online{Microwave,
    author = "Jim Lucas",
    title = "What Are Microwaves?",
    year = "2018", 
    url = "https://www.livescience.com/50259-microwaves.html",
    note = {Accessed on 25/02/2018}      
}

@online{Transducer,
    author = "CyberPhysics",
    title = "The Piezoelectric Transducer",
    year = "2018", 
    url = "http://www.cyberphysics.co.uk/topics/medical/Ultrasound/PETransducer.html",
    note = "(accessed on 23/02/2018)"     
}

@online{Peffect,
    author = "D. Vatansever and E Siores and T. Shah",
    title = "Alternative Resources for Renewable Energy: Piezoelectric and Photovoltaic Smart Structures",
    year = "2012", 
    url = "https://www.intechopen.com/books/global-warming-impacts-and-future-perspective/alternative-resources-for-renewable-energy-piezoelectric-and-photovoltaic-smart-structures",
    note = {Accessed on 23/02/2018}     
}

@online{InversePeffect,
    author = "Carmen Emily Yang ",
    title = "What is the Piezoelectric Effect?",
    year = "2016", 
    url = "http://www.electronicdesign.com/power/what-piezoelectric-effect",
    note = {Accessed on 23/02/2018}         
}

@online{PulseEcho ,
    author = "Barnana Pal",
    title = "Pulse-echo method can't measure wave attenuation accurately",
    year = "2014",
    url = "http://www.electronicdesign.com/power/what-piezoelectric-effect",
    note = {Accessed on 23/03/2018}     
}

@online{HarbourPorpoise,
    author = "Lee A. Miller and Magnus Wahlberg",
    title = {Echolocation by the harbour porpoise: life in coastal waters},
    year = "2013",
    url = "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3625834/",
    note = {Accessed on 26/03/2018}     
}

@online{UltrasonicFrogs,
    author = "Albert S. Feng and Peter M. Narins and Chun-He Xu and Wen-Yu Lin and Zu-Lin Yu and Qiang Qiu and Zhi-Min Xu and Jun-Xian Shen",
    title = {Ultrasonic communication in frogs},
    year = "2006",
    xurl = "https://www.nature.com/articles/nature04416.epdf?referrer_access_token=LNiCFtk3I0dn2v_AQJi7L9RgN0jAjWel9jnR3ZoTv0Mg8z7v5gDUqEkMtxgbkmfnvtnkk6K-DSpQAwlhEv7S09o7Z1CcRAGZ-jRhIZrCBxEnNLEm-Hh2WWuS7KsV2QRDgRk1XxPWezWv0JDp4VGznNDREMvAIetTrYWhs-_WUHSXAiAcnqL4ZFrjt7BaN85qwq1dToDeNugpAcT9jN9--j-DNo5sboys5-h8E0-gCYE%3D&tracking_referrer=www.nature.com
    ",
    note = {Accessed on 30/03/2018}     
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[comma]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{ref}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: Another thing I wanted to point out is that your near-exclusive use of `@online` as the bibliographic entry type is almost certainly misguided. For instance, the publication with key `UltrasonicFrogs` was published in the journal *Nature*. You should employ the entry type `@article`:

```
@article{UltrasonicFrogs,
    author  = "Albert S. Feng and Peter M. Narins and Chun-He Xu and 
               Wen-Yu Lin and Zu-Lin Yu and Qiang Qiu and Zhi-Min Xu 
               and Jun-Xian Shen",
    title   = "Ultrasonic communication in frogs",
    journal = "Nature",
    year    = 2006,
    volume  = 440,
    pages   = "333--336",
    url     = "https://www.nature.com/articles/nature04416.epdf",     
}
```

Observe that the publication's URL can (and almost certainly should!) be shortened drastically from what you provided in your posting. 
Observe also that I
deleted the `note` field with its "accessed on ..." blurb, because accessed-on-date information is just about irrelevant for articles published in journals.

You should probably make an effort to go through your entire bibliography and decide which entries that are currently of type `@online` should really be given entry types such as `@article`, `@book`, `@techreport`, etc. For sure, the piece by Miller and Wahlberg, which was published in the journal *Frontiers in Physiology *, ought to be of type `@article` as well.

Comment: Thank you so much, the only reason I have been using 'agsm' is I need too use Harvard referencing and that was the one recommended to me. Is there another style which may work instead?

Comment: @LukeFarrell - "harvard-style" citing is also known as (better known as?!) "authoryear-style" citing. There is a LaTeX package called "harvard" (which provides several style files, including `agsm`). However, there are lots and lots of other style files that also allow the creation of authoryear-style citation call-outs. Since you're using the `natbib` citation management package, I'd suggest you employ the `abbrvnat` bib style and see if you like it. If and when you submit your paper to a journal, the journal will likely require the use of yet another style file.

Comment: Thanks again, it took a few tries but I managed to get it to work with`abbrvnat ` and following what you said.